# Show multiple paths of equal length in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

If there are multiple paths from a source to destination, how do I get these ALL of these paths using NetworkX? Note that this is a simplified example, I want to actually be using the nx.all_pairs_shortest_path() function and get all shortest paths between any two nodes.

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)])
nx.draw(G)
print(nx.shortest_path(G,0,3))
```

Output I Get:

```
[0, 1, 3]
```

Output I Want:

```
[[0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`all_shortest_paths` does what you're after, but it is a generator.  If you want a list, then put `list` around it

```
shortest_path_generator = nx.all_shortest_paths(G,0,3)
list(shortest_path_generator)
```